# How can I connect to a website using twill inside of google app engine's python sandbox?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twill

this allows me to connect to a website with python on my computer:

```
from twill.commands import go, show, showforms, formclear, fv, submit

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

go('http://www.pge.com')
showforms()
```

this gets me to hello world on google app engine, with the twill and beautiful soup imports working:

```
import webapp2
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
from twill.commands import go, show, showforms, formclear, fv, submit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!  I love dog food.')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

now after this i try to connect to a website using twill and fail:

where can i call go() to connect to a website?

if I add it before `class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):` it hangs and I don't get to hello world.

If I add it inside the MainPage class on the first line as either `getit = go('http://www.pge.com')`, or just `go('http://www.pge.com')`, it also hangs and I don't get to hello world.

If I add it inside `def: get(self):`, I get:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the
>   requested operation.
>   and a bunch of stuff about twill and mechanize.py, followed by

`File "..../twill/utils.py", line 275, in run_tidy
    process = subprocess.Popen(_tidy_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'`

am i somehow missing some other dependencies, like mechanize.py?  or is there something else i need to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

This helped partially solve my issue, but other problems cropped up later, particularly in filling forms, submitting them, and migrating further in the website.

```
import webapp2
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
from twill.commands import go, show, showforms, formclear, fv, submit, config
from twill.browser import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    config('use_tidy', '0')
    def get(self):
        go('http://www.pge.com')

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!  I love dog food.')
        self.response.write(show())
```

tidy is disabled in this way (tidy does not play well with the google sandbox), and I am able to show() the webpage via `self.response.write(show())`.

As a side note: be careful about using TextEdit to edit .py files when working with google app engine.  I was getting all sorts of weird non-ascii character errors.  I added # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- to the first line of the python file, which sort-of helped, and switched to using pycharm's ide which really helped.

twill is giving me all sorts of issues inside google app engine's sandbox that i am not getting on my system.  i can get finally the html for one webpage, but can't submit forms in the way i was doing so simply on my system. showforms() isn't even showing the forms, maybe because i disabled tidy and the html is not being parsed properly?

i think one way to move forward here is to get tidy to work inside twill.  obviously roadblocks are being hit "under the hood", and they are hard for me to see.

it seems like twill is a high level abstraction and maybe is not a good idea right now for using on google app engine.  next i will try to switch to mechanize.py, or look for another sandbox, maybe amazon?